# Intercepting Request and Response in Spring + Jersey application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

I have spring boot application which has both Jersey endpoints and Spring mvc endpoints. I would like to intercept request and response from a single point for both types of enpoint.

So far I know there is three option to do that. Those are- `Filter`, `Spring Interceptor` and `Spring @ControllerAdvice`. Among them `Interceptor` and `ControllerAdvice` is only applicable for Spring endpoints and it doesn't work for Jersey endpoints. Only the `Filter` is so far working for both endpoints. Is there any other way I can intercept request/response both for Jersey and Spring mvc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filter sounds perfect for both. What's the problem?

Comment: My requirements is to log both request and response body. It looks like I need to do lots of low-level (OutputStream etc) coding to extract the content from `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` object. This is the part I wanted to avoid. I was wondering if there any Spring boot way to do it both for Spring mvc and Jersey endpoints.

Comment: There is `org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` that may or may not be enough for your needs. You can write your own, using the above as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use Spring's `@RequestBodyAdvice` and `@ResponseBodyAdvice` if you are on Spring 4.2+ but I'm not sure it will work with Jersey. This will depend on your project setup. All in all, standard JEE `Filter` is the easiest choice here.